# Contradiction symbol "upside-down T"

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am looking for a Latex command to print the mathematical contradiction symbol, which is the upside-down T.

Comment: Do you mean `\bot`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Comprehensive Symbol Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) is your flexible friend concerning lookup of thousands of symbols:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$\bot\bot\bot$

\end{document}
```

[image]